# NodeJS change file and folder permissions

Tags: node.js, windows

I'm currently running a node application with elevated privileges on Windows and am creating folders and writing files to disk. How can I change the permissions of these files and folders so elevated privileges aren't required in order to edit and/or delete them?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ICACLS` in Command Prompt in Windows 7 or later.

For earlier versions you can use `CACLS`.

Here is the usage example:

```
ICACLS "filename" /grant "Users":F
```

This will give all users in `Users` group the `Full` privilege.