# When using npm, commands fail due to cache access restriction/lock (errno EBUSY -4082)

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, electron

#### Problem

I've been running into what appears to be a directory access issue in Windows when attempting to use `npm`. Having tried numerous suggestions from various other SO questions and answers, I thought I'd see if anyone might have suggestions or solutions based on log the output.

I'm continuously running into the error anytime I attempt an `npm` operation, including `install` (global or local), `uninstall`, `update`, or executing tools such as `electron-packager` as shown in the `package.json` scripts section, below the error itself.

#### Information

- Operating system: Windows 10 (Build 19043)
- `node` version: v18.3.0
- `npm` version: 8.12.1

The error output itself is typically
:

```
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\a870f111
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\d3\23\a585f82ed54ccfe948a39da16e212d9b112d87f43f74100e4e56c7f688e670ed506b8e7b57284c0a7c268503abcc5569023fcaa73f00b1c4f7670d5c2537
npm ERR! errno -4082
npm ERR! EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\a870f111' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\d3\23\a585f82ed54ccfe948a39da16e212d9b112d87f43f74100e4e56c7f688e670ed506b8e7b57284c0a7c268503abcc5569023fcaa73f00b1c4f7670d5c2537'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-04T18_34_40_792Z-debug-0.log
```

Full log output: [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/D9XTSp0d)

`package.json`

```
{
    "name": "MyElectronApp",
    "productName": "MyElectronApp",
    "desktopName": "MyElectronApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Foobar",
    "main": "app.js",
    "repository": "https://github.com/",
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "cognophile",
    "license": "GNU General Public License v3.0",
    "files": [
        "app.js",
        "assets/styles.css",
        "resources/icon.png",
        "resources/icon.ico",
        "resources/icon.icns"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "start": "npx electron .",
        "build": "npm run build:macos && npm run build:linux && npm run build:windows",
        "build:macos": "npx electron-packager . --overwrite --asar --out=dist --ignore='^media$' --prune --platform=darwin --arch=x64 --icon=resources/icon.icns --app-bundle-id=com.cognophile.myelectronapp --app-version=$npm_package_version && cd dist/MyElectronApp-darwin-x64 && zip -ryXq9 ../MyElectronApp-macos-${npm_package_version}.zip MyElectronApp.app",
        "build:linux": "npx electron-packager . --overwrite --out=dist --ignore='^media$' --prune --platform=linux --arch=x64 --icon=resources/icon.png --app-bundle-id=com.cognophile.myelectronapp --app-version=$npm_package_version && cd dist/MyElectronApp-linux-x64/ && zip -ryq9 ../MyElectronApp-linux-${npm_package_version}.zip *",
        "build:windows": "npx electron-packager . --overwrite --asar --out=dist --ignore='^media$' --prune --platform=win32 --arch=ia32 --icon=resources/icon.ico --version-string.ProductName=$npm_package_productName --app-version=$npm_package_version && cd dist/MyElectronApp-win32-ia32 && zip -ryq9 ../MyElectronApp-windows-${npm_package_version}.zip *"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^13.6.6",
        "electron-builder": "^22.4.1",
        "electron-packager": "^14.2.1"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "about-window": "^1.15.2"
    }
}
```

Trying to run the scripts results in the same error, with differing details. For example, trying to execute the `npm start` script. The same is true for `npm run build:windows`, but the unfetchable package URL in the error is `https://registry.npmjs.org/electron-packager`

```
❯ npm start
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> MyElectronApp@1.0.0 start
> npx electron .

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code EBUSY
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\01286790
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1b\71\c52f6c1e74e5c3c22e0f872bae840fa8e460c356b5c1f807c437a1f8cad2b7bfeb884bb387cbd8012a08d5deaa4b1395f5d4d1cfbc00cfd1b4f5c5e201e3
npm ERR! errno EBUSY
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/electron: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\01286790' -> 'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\1b\71\c52f6c1e74e5c3c22e0f872bae840fa8e460c356b5c1f807c437a1f8cad2b7bfeb884bb387cbd8012a08d5deaa4b1395f5d4d1cfbc00cfd1b4f5c5e201e3'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-04T19_08_01_775Z-debug-0.log
```

#### Attempted solutions

I've tried a number of suggestions from a variety of sources, including ([npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall rename [StackOverflow])](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714012/nodejs-change-file-and-folder-permissions):

- Clearing the cache with `npm cache clean --force` then reinstalling (`npm install`)
- Verifying the cache with `npm cache verify` then reinstralling (`npm install`)
- Removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`, clearing the cache, and reinstalling
- Removing `read-only` checkbox from project folder and cache folder (right-click > properties) which seems to immediately get reset

I've tried these in dedicated PowerShell terminals (non-admin and admin), and the integrated terminal in Visual Studio Code, all having the same result. I've also tried:

- Repairing the `nodejs` installation via the installer
- Uninstalling `nodejs` and removing `node`/`npm` related files and directories, restarting the PC, and reinstalling `nodejs` and attempting `npm install` in a fresh PowerShell terminal
- Rebooting to ensure no other processes are using these directories (such as `vscode` or another terminal instance)
- Closing anti-virus program (not attempted a full uninstall) and trying the above solutions

I suspect this relates to permissions on the cache directories, judging by the error message, but since it is `npm` which creates those directories after the `npm cache clean`, I'm not sure I understand what more is needed, and am naturally hesitant to change directory permissions (e.g. [NodeJS change file and folder permissions [StackOverflow]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31714012/nodejs-change-file-and-folder-permissions))  until having received advice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Relaunch terminal as Admin and you should be able to get over this.

To do the same in Windows,

Shift + Right-click "Terminal" → Run as Administrator

Let me know it that works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).